# Getting "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of" on reddit API

Tags: java, android, json, reddit

Hello I'm trying to use this endpoint www.reddit.com/reddits.json to show some list on android and I'm getting this error, below is my code.

I have this asynctask class on my main activity class:

```
private class AsyncListLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>{

    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String REDEEM_URL = "http://www.reddit.com/reddits.json";
    private HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(REDEEM_URL, "GET", param);
        if (json != null) {
            Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());
            return json;
        }
        else {
            Log.d("JSON result", "is null");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject s) {
        try {
            if(!s.has("kind")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                JSONObject list = s.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray childrens = list.getJSONArray("children");
                for(int i = 0; i < childrens.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject o = childrens.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");
                    Feed f = new Feed(o.getString("icon_img"),o.getString("banner_img"),o.getString("display_name"));
                    MainActivity.this.adapter.add(f);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

makehttpRequest when get:

```
if(method.equals("GET")){
        // request method is GET

        if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
            url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
        }

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;
```

I tested out another json endpoints on the web and they are working. I dont have any idea why is this happening.

EDIT:

- No param is being used so the url is fine.
- The json is valid, I checked this in differents websites.

Comment: `JSONException` = something went wrong, `End of input at character 0 of”` = just got "" and don't know how to *json-ize* it.

Comment: IMHO: `conn.setDoOutput(false);` is the culprit here

Comment: I removed and changed the to     conn.setDoOutput(true); and nothing happens @RC.

Comment: use retrofit, seriously.